# Show current time of most commons timezone (UTC, EDT, CEST...)

Tags: linux, bash, date

I can have UTC current time with "date -u".
But i would like to print the current time of some common timezones at the same time. (UTC, EDT, CEST...)

I can create a script and add severals :

```
date -u -d 'x hour ago'
```

But sometimes, hours change. (Like in France)
Is there another solution to have the "real" current time, based on the country / cities maybe ?

**EDIT :**
Here what i have done with the answer :

```
function dateall(){
    echo -n "US Pacific : " && TZ=US/Pacific date
    echo -n "US Eastern : " && TZ=US/Eastern date
    echo -n "UTC ~ GMT : " && date -u
    echo -n "Europe Paris : " && TZ=Europe/Paris date
    echo -n "Asia Bangkok : " && TZ=Asia/Bangkok date
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can point `TZ` to the timezone you want:

```
$ TZ=Europe/Paris date
Fri Jun 12 07:41:28 CEST 2015
```

Comment: Not really a universal solution if you take daylight savings into account.

Comment: @Arpith I'm not sure I understand your objection.  Timezones deal with DST that automatically.  Compare f.i. `TZ=Europe/Paris date -d '12 Dec 2015'` to `TZ=Europe/Paris date -d '12 Jun 2015'`.

Answer (score 1):

In my dateutils there's [`datezone`](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#datezone) to do what you want in one simple command:

```
$ datezone now Europe/Paris US/Pacific US/Eastern UTC
2015-06-12T08:23:32+02:00   Europe/Paris
2015-06-11T23:23:32-07:00   US/Pacific
2015-06-12T02:23:32-04:00   US/Eastern
2015-06-12T06:23:32+00:00   UTC
2015-06-12T13:23:32+07:00   Asia/Bangkok
$
```

with the additional advantage that you also get the current UTC offsets and the times are guaranteed to coincide, i.e. the current time is determined only once and then used for all timezone conversions.